# Why does the limit not change in the given summation series even after substituting $p=-n$ in the given question?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$
\begin{align}
DFS[x^*(-n)] &= \frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}x^*(-n)e^{-j2\pi kn/N}\\
&= \left[\frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-1}_{n=0}x(-n)e^{j2\pi kn/N}\right]^*\\
&= \left[\frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-1}_{p=0}x(p)e^{-j2\pi kp/N}\right]^*\\
&= c^*_k
\end{align}
$$

([Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P5nK.png))

In the given series we have substituted $p=-n$ and limit for $n$ is from $0$ to $N-1$. Therefore, the limit for $p$ should be from $0$ to $1-N$, but limit is still the same. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: If $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character mod(N), then you just need to note that each sum is a sum over all the residues mod(N).

Comment: it is not specified weather x(n) is even or odd...and i  am just asking you about the limits of p ,i think it should be from 0 to 1-N instead of 0 to N-1 as we have substituted p=-n and limit of n is from 0 to N-1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed $x$ is $N$ periodic ($x(n+N) = x(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$). 
Also that $j=\sqrt{-1}$ is the imaginary unit.
Then, $\theta\mapsto e^{-j\theta}$ is $2\pi$ periodic, thus $n\mapsto e^{-j2\pi k n/N}$ is also $N$ periodic.

Thus, by periodicity we have
\begin{align} 
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(-n) e^{j2\pi k n/N} 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(-n) e^{-j2\pi k (-n)/N} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(N-n) e^{-j2\pi k (N-n)/N} \\
&= \sum_{p=1}^{N} x(p) e^{-j2\pi k p/N} \\
&= \sum_{p=0}^{N-1} x(p) e^{-j2\pi k p/N}.
\end{align}
The last equality follows from $x(N) e^{-j2\pi k N/N} = x(0) e^{-j2\pi k \cdot 0/N}$.